# Sed : replace words only with first occurrence of string in the line not till last match

Tags: regex, sed

I am stuck at one point in my script. Can you please help with this.

Problem : there is a file with lines:

```
"<abc>-group ab:cd:ef +define_1 +DEFINE_2 </abc>"
```

Now i want to remove `-group ab:cd:ef` from all the lines in that file.
I tried with

```
%s/-group .* //g
```

but it will remove all the test till the last space. and the new text will become `<abc></abc>` where as i want something like this :

```
<abc>+define_1 +DEFINE_2 </abc>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/-group [^ ]* /,"")}1' file
"<abc>+define_1 +DEFINE_2 </abc>"
```

Or this `sed`

```
sed -r 's/-group [^ ]* //' file
"<abc>+define_1 +DEFINE_2 </abc>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using sed

```
sed 's/-group [[:graph:]]* //' file
```

in vi/vim:

```
%s/-group [[:graph:]]* //g
```

Comment: The `sed` gives an extra space after `<abc>`, should be:`sed 's/-group [[:graph:]]* //'`

Answer (score 0):

you should change the `search & replace` expression to something like this:

```
`%s/-group ab:cd:ef //g`
```

It would avoid the whole line matching.

Comment: I guess `ab` `cd` `ef` just represent characters, not just `ab` etc.

Comment: Yes. ab cd ef are just representation of different words. They are different in different lines.